# PHP redirect custom variable URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect the following URL:

```
/folder/Some%20Variable%20File%20Name
```

to

```
/folder/some-variable-file-name
```

When users visit `example.com/videos/Bollywood%20Movie%202016` directly.

**Note:** I want to redirect lots of variables and not just the above URL. The above URL is just for explanation.

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to the problem:

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
if (stripos("$uri", "%20")) {
$uri = strtolower($uri);
$uri = str_replace("%20", "-", $uri);
$uri = str_replace(" ", "-", $uri);
header("Location: $uri");
exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Redirect "/videos/Bollywood%20movie%202016" /videos/Bollywood-movie-2016
```

Comment: There are thousands of similar URLs that I want to redirect.